# Firebase Cloud Function Keep return "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created some functions in firebase cloud functions, but all of them are works. But i have a new function which is not work properly. I don't know why but i think it has same pattern with others.

this is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const appVideo = express();
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });


appVideo.use(cors);

appVideo.get('/update-video', async(req, res) => {
  console.log('updateStatusVideo idCourse', req.query.idCourse, ' idMateri: ', req.query.idMateri, ' idVideo:', req.query.idVideo);

  res.status(200).send('Oke')
})

exports.video = functions.https.onRequest(appVideo)
```

I often call partial deploy like
`firebase deploy --only functions:video`. But when i execute the functions https through browser it often return

> Request failed with status code 404

other weird things is when i inspect the browser and switch to console, i found

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

this is the url of function in firebase:

> https://us-central1-my-apps.cloudfunctions.net/video [modified for confidential]

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to access `https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/video/update-video`?

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear about how exactly you are trying to run this function.  The question should contain enough detail that anyone can reproduce the behavior you observe.  Without knowing the URL, we don't know if you're even specifying it correctly.

Comment: @samthecodingman yes

Comment: @DougStevenson this is my function which registered in firebase: `https://us-central1-my-apps.cloudfunctions.net/video`

Comment: @samthecodingman but the url in my firebase is `https://us-central1-my-apps.cloudfunctions.net/video`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export this line:

```js
exports.video = functions.https.onRequest(appVideo);
```

You define a Cloud Function called `video` that is deployed as `https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/video` where `PROJECT_ID` is whatever your Firebase Project ID is.

Because you use a `express` application for this exported function, any URL that is handled must first start with `https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/video` (the `BASE_URL`).

This line:

```js
appVideo.get('/update-video', ...)
```

attaches a listener to `BASE_URL/update-video`, which becomes `https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/video/update-video`.

If you want to use just `https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/video` as-is, you'll need to change to using

```js
appVideo.get('/', ...)
```

If you want to use just `https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/update-video`, you'll need to change to using

```js
appVideo.get('/', ...)
```

and

```js
exports.update = {};
exports.update.video = functions.https.onRequest(appVideo);
// "update.video" is deployed as "update-video"
```

**Note:** This last part abuses [deploying groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions) to get the desired URL

Comment: So, we can not extend https://us-central1-my-apps.cloudfunctions.net/video (BASE_URL) to specific path /update-video ?

Comment: @NandaZ The function name is required and can't be removed. You could use [Firebase Hosting rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions) to get whatever URL format you want or you can use the "hack" I added to my answer.